# CSS to constrain 960px inside a div?

Tags: html, css

At the moment I have this (standard) code which gives me a full-width background but constrains the header to centered 960px:

```
<div style="background-color: #222">
    <header style="width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>Site Title</h1>
    </header>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can apply those to a single element in CSS, and avoid the `div` altogether? I considered [this jQuery hack](http://jsfiddle.net/s7aGN/) to calculate and set left and right padding on `header` but a pure CSS solution would be better.

Desired HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
</header>
```

It might not be possible but thought I'd ask before dismissing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ditch the div wrapper in favor of `:before` and `:after`. Here's an article on it: http://css-tricks.com/9443-full-browser-width-bars/

The end of the article has a link to information on which browsers support `:before` and `:after`. For those that don't, you could use a javascript polyfill.

Comment: Unfortunately that still requires a wrapper to constrain my `header` to 960px in the first place. I tried setting 960px and auto margins on `body` but it got upset. Thanks though, great link and CSS trick

Comment: @Tak I'm confused, how does this require a wrapper element? http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/25hAr/

Comment: Looks terrible in Firefox 3.6 :( Now I'm in Chrome and I see what you mean, that's exactly what I'm after

Comment: @Tak, Hm. weird. I did forget to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body`, but that didn't fix it for me in jsfiddle on FF 3.6. Though the demo (http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullBrowserWidthBars/) looks fine for me on FF 3.6.

Comment: Yea works fine locally too, not sure why jsfiddle is playing hard to get. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

if it's for the whole page you can set the background on the `<body>` otherwise I think you'll need to use a `<div>` like you have.

Answer (score 0):

Would something as this simple work?

```
header {
    background-color: #222;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1 {
    background: #fcc;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Edit this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6wBv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I take it this is HTML5 you're working with? There's no need to wrap a div around a header. This is one of the beautiful things about HTML5!

What I would do is give this particular header an ID, and stylize from there. For instance:

Your CSS file (or included CSS):

```
#title {
   background-color: #222;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 960px;
   }
```

Your HTML:

```
<header id=#title>
   <h1>Site Title</h1>
</header>
```

[This link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/) kind of does the same thing you're looking to do!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible using just a single element. Thanks to the fact that padding in percentage refers to [parent's width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#padding).
In [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnj92/) I used `div` but it should work with `header` as well.